# Specifying just a setter on a set/getter

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm using getters and setters for creating an instance of a class.

Is it possible to adjust the value being set without having to have a private variable, and do it on the type directly?

For example, if my class is:

```
public class Cat()
{
public String Age{get; set; }
}
```

and I want to instantiate it doing:

```
new Cat({Age: "3"});
```

Now, if I have a function called ConvertToHumanYears that I want to call before it is being stored, I would imagine something like this is the right way:

```
public class Cat()
{
public String Age{get; set{ value = ConvertToHumanYears(value); }
}
```

But the above (and many dirivatives of it) seem to return errors. Is it possible to do something similar without having to have an additional private variable I set and get?

Comment: This looks a lot like VB, why tag it as C#?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You cannot use auto property for getter and have a definition for setter.

it's either

```
public class Cat()
{
   public String Age{get; set; }
}
```

or

```
public class Cat()
{
  private String _age;

    public String Age{
      get{
          return _age;
      }
      set{
           _age = ConvertToHumanYears(value); 
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: ah, that's what I have, but I was hoping to have it clean without the addition of a private variable :(

Comment: Reason for this is the Compiler actually creates the private variable on the fly at runtime, so you cant mix it up. @StackOverFlowException is correct.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
public class Cat
{
    public string Age { get; private set; }
}
```

You have to have the setter, but it's callable only inside the class itself.

You can then create a constructor that allows setting the value:

```
public Cat(string age)
{
    Age = age;
}
```

or

```
public Cat(string age)
{
    Age = ConvetToHumanYears(age);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it's no use but I had a similar problem where I just wanted set to be private and get to be public, instead of specifying the setter I marked it private. I didn't now we could do that.

```
public String Age{get; private set; }
```

Sometimes the more obvious it is, the more difficult it is to find.
Hope this helps someone !