# how to assign value in asp.net List variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have list variable which is filled by data fetch from db in code behind.
After fetching data in list , can i replace a list variable value?
here is my list

```
public  class SummaryInformation
{
   
    public long Id { get { return parent.Id; } }

    public string TypeCode { get { return parent.TypeCode; } }
}
```

---

Code for fetching data and replacing list value

```
string sTypeCode = "C"
SummaryInformation account = Account.GetSummary(long.Parse(lb.CommandArgument), currentUser, lb.Attribute("Id"));
List<SummaryInformation> accounts = new List<SummaryInformation>();
```

Now once the list loaded here from db data then can i replace TypeCode db value with my value in list?
like below

```
accounts.ElementAt(1) = sTypeCode ;
```

i am getting error when i tried to assign list value like this.

Comment: What is the error you are getting.?

Comment: @SmithaKalluz error is "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer" , i think its not correct way of assignment a value in list

Comment: have you tried accounts[1] = sTypeCode

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.item?view=net-6.0

Comment: @SmithaKalluz yes I tried it says can not implicitly change string to entity class

Comment: @NickBailey your link is not having solution for this issue

Comment: first you should change class SummaryInformation
replace public string TypeCode { get { return parent.TypeCode; } } 
to public string TypeCode { get { return parent.TypeCode; } set{parent?.TypeCode = value;}}
and use 
accounts.ElementAt(0)?. = sTypeCode

Comment: @KreminT when i included set in SummaryInformation error then it says ""The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer""

Comment: The syntax for setting a value in a list is `list[index] = value`. It's right there in the docs and the same as index notation in C, C++, JavaScript, Python, Ruby and basically every other language.

Comment: @VimalSingh try accounts.ElementAt(0)?.TypeCode =sTypeCode ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to override your DB `TypeCode` value to your `sTypeCode`:

```
string sTypeCode = "C"
SummaryInformation account = Account.GetSummary(long.Parse(lb.CommandArgument), currentUser, lb.Attribute("Id"));
List<SummaryInformation> accounts = new List<SummaryInformation>();
account.TypeCode=sTypeCode;
//Add to your list
accounts.Add(account);
```

You also need to use Automatic Properties to your getter and setter:

```
public string TypeCode {get;set;}
```

Comment: Let me try and get back to you.....

Comment: this solution is also giving error "Property or indexer 'SummaryInformation.TypeCode' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"

Comment: @VimalSingh Your property has no setter, which makes it a readonly property, therefore you are getting this error: `public string TypeCode { get { return parent.TypeCode; } set { parent.TypeCode=value; }}` or simply: `public string TypeCode {get;set}`

Comment: hey Rahul , when i include set in SummaryInformation class error then it says ""The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer""

Comment: @VimalSingh What is `parent.TypeCode`? You cannot assign something to a function result hence you are getting the error. You can look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131159/specifying-just-a-setter-on-a-set-getter

Comment: i tried public string TypeCode {get;set} and its perfectly working........